# How to customize figure caption in `typst`

Tags: figure, caption, typst

I want to make like this:

```
    [another text rather than table 1-1] some text to display.  
    [another text rather than table 1-2] some text to display.  
    [another text rather than table 2-1] some text to display.  
    [another text rather than table 2-2] some text to display.
```

maximum 2-depth, first depth to corresponding to heading number, and next depth to continuous digit.

Please help.

I tried with this code but it doesn't work.

```
    [1-1] only numbered 1, 2, 3, ...  
    1-2] numbered like 1-2, 2-2, ...
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CT7fF.png)

Answer (score 1):

**DISCLAIMER: This answer only handles the "another text rather than table" part.**

There are several ways to do this, which can be done with both table and image:

1. You can change this text (called `supplement` in typst) for each instance, such as to gain `IMAGE 1: here comes text`:

   ```
    #figure(
      image("image.png"),
      caption: [here comes text],
      supplement: [IMAGE],
    ) <test_img>
   ```

   Now you also have to match the referencing via: `@test_img[IMAGE]` (this overwrites the document-wide supplement in-place)
2. You can make it a document-wide thing. For the figure instance:

   ```
    #show figure: it => block(width: 100%)[#align(center)[
        #it.body
        // #it.supplement // original
        #getSupplement(it) // replacing function
        #it.counter.display(it.numbering):
        #it.caption
    ]]
   ```

   The function `getSupplement()` replaces the supplement according to your rules. Because you have to distinct between `image` and `table`, the following could be done, making it possible to replace either:

   ```
    #let getSupplement(it) = {
        // see in "View Example": https://typst.app/docs/reference/meta/ref/#parameters-supplement
        if it.func() == figure and it.kind == table {
            [MyTable]
        } else if it.func() == figure and it.kind == image {
            [MyImage]
        } else { // keep original
            it.supplement
        }
    }
   ```

   This would produce for your table `MyTable 1: here comes text`. Now, you also have to make the `ref` part change document-wide:

   ```
    #set ref(supplement: it => {
        getSupplement(it)
    })
   ```

   **WARNING: This (bullet point 2.) seems to overwrite the custom settings which could be done otherwise via bullet point 1.!**
3. Change the language of the text, so the correct supplements are used accordingly, i.e. for German (not sure which languages are available though):

   ```
    #set text(lang: "de")
   ```